# How to correctly build a relation 1:M in aggregate using DDD and ORM?

Tags: hibernate, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

I have two entities: `Rule` and `Violation`, 1:M.

There are two possible ways of how this relation in ORM could be designed:

- 1:M Bidirectional, when we have `rule_id` foreign key in the `violations` table
- 1:m [Unidirectional](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) with Join Table, when we have 3 tables: `rules`, `violations` and `rule_violation`.

From what I have read in theory of DDD, the Rule is an Aggregate Root and we can only have access to Violation through its aggregate root - Rule entity.

Question is what relation should be used of two above and how to design entities.

For example it's not clear whether the Violation entity should have a `ruleId` inside it or not.

Is it correct to have such constructor:

```
class Violation
{
    public function __construct(ViolationId $vid, RuleId $rid, /* other parameters /*)
}
```

Or just like this

```
class Violation
{
    public function __construct(ViolationId $vid, /* other parameters /*)
}
```

If it's ok to have `ruleId` inside Violation, then how to map it with ORM (Hibernate or Doctrine). Because Doctrine works with relations and objects, not with simple integers.

Please advice.

Answer (score 4):

The rule of thumb is to first design your model and then figure out how to persist it. At that point your persistence framework may force you to make a few adjustments to it in order to make it persistable, but you shouldn't pick a persistence framework that will force you to pollute your model with too many persistence concerns.

For instance, if `Violation` is part of the `Rule` aggregate then from the model perspective, `Violation` probably do not have to hold a reference to it's `Rule` since all `Violation` manipulations are initiated through the root. However, depending how you model the behaviors internally you may also want the bi-directionnal association, but it shouldn't have anything to do with persistence at this point.

Now, if your persistence framework of choice requires a `Violation` to hold the `ruleId` then you may have to make this adjustment to your model and pollute your model with persistence concerns in order to be pragmatic. However, try as much as possible not to let the persistence framework drive your model and if it impacts your model too much then perhaps the framework is not flexible enough to offer persistence ignorance and you should consider switching.